# wrapping text of range marker label in jfree chart

Tags: java, jfreechart

hey folks please help me out to wrap a range marker text label in jfree chart.the text is so long that at times it cuts off so I want to wrap the text when it surpasses the limit to avoid getting cut off.

```
Marker rangeMarkerCutoff= new ValueMarker(cutoff);
rangeMarkerCutoff.setPaint(Color.white);               
rangeMarkerCutoff.setLabelFont(helveticaBold18);
String markerCutoffString=benchmarkLabel+" "+cutoff.intValue()+"%";
markerCutoffString=wrapMarkerLabel(markerCutoffString);
rangeMarkerCutoff.setLabel(markerCutoffString);
rangeMarkerCutoff.setLabelOffset(new RectangleInsets(1,35,20,85));
rangeMarkerCutoff.setLabelBackgroundColor(Color.white);
rangeMarkerCutoff.setLabelAnchor(RectangleAnchor.TOP_RIGHT);

plot.addRangeMarker(rangeMarkerCutoff);
```

here **markerCutoffString** has to be wrapped 
I have used function **wrapMarkerLabel** like this but it is of no use

```
private static final String wrapMarkerLabel(String label) {
    String wrappedlabel = WordUtils.wrap(label,-100);
    return wrappedlabel;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot to explain the problem? A runnable piece of code would also be helpful.

Comment: Why the `-100`? Why not a positive value? Perhaps try with `WordUtils.wrap(label, 20, "<br>", false)`. I'm not sure, but it is possible that the HTML tag `<br>` will be recognized (instead of the default newline character).

Comment: Can you suggest some other ways to do it?